# jQuery Reloading MySQL Output (Browser Issue)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, google-chrome

I'm using a small jQuery script I found online and having some difficulty understanding why it's working in almost every browser except Chrome. My jQuery skills are nominal at best but I have the following code placed inside a PHP page I'm creating..

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      refreshTable();
    });

    function refreshTable(){
        $('#tableHolder').load('counter.php', function(){
           setTimeout(refreshTable, 1000);
        });
    }
</script>
```

This code is supposed to call my counter.php file which contains a small amount of PHP that calls back results from a MySQL database, for testing purposes I reduced it's output to a simple echo statement.

```
<?php echo "Hello World"; ?>
```

This code was working in Chrome as of last night and I don't think I've changed anything that would impact whether or not it worked in a browser. I've tested it in others browsers and it still works in everything. Firefox is sometimes working and sometimes not.

What can I do to make this work in all browsers or at least Chrome and Firefox as they're most commonly used?

Comment: do you have `<div id="tableHolder"></div>` in your page? Are there any errors in the browser console?

Comment: I did indeed have the div tag I actually just found the problem, I checked the console and it was throwing an error because I'm loading the jQuery library without using HTTPS. Your comment helped me solve this!

Comment: When in doubt, browser console :)

Comment: Thanks for your help! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Checked the Chrome Console and found an error saying that because I'm using HTTPS on the website I was deploying this code to, I also needed to include HTTPS in the url for the jQuery library.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
```